# What would my Form PHP code have to be to send this field?

Tags: forms

HTML USED:

```
<p><strong>Lesson Type<span class="red">*</span></strong></p>
<select name="cf_package_type" class="cf_package_type" size="1" class="option">
    <option value="100">Beginner Lesson - R100</option>
    <option value="130">Advanced Lesson - R130</option>
    <option value="160">Professional Lesson - R160</option>
</select>

<p><strong>No. of Lessons<span class="red">*</span></strong></p>
<select id="number-of-lessons" name="cf_number" size="1" class="cf_number" class="option" onchange='test()'>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
    <option name="2" value="2">2</option>
    <option name="3" value="3">3</option>
    <option name="4" value="4">4</option>
</select>

<input type="text" value="100" disabled="disabled" id="result">
```

JS Used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        var val1 = +parseInt($(".cf_package_type").val());
        var val2 = +parseInt($(".cf_number").val());
        $("#result").val(val1*val2);
    });
});
```

The amount due won't appear when sending the form. How do i echo the amount onto  the page that it gets redirected to upon form submission and how do i get the amount to appear in the email received.

http://jsfiddle.net/GuBPL/28/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this on the PHP page:

```
<?php

echo $_POST['cf_number'];

?>
```

You might want to do some validation as well, check if it's numeric for example:

```
<?php

if( is_numeric($_POST['cf_number']) ) {
   echo $_POST['cf_number'];
} else {
  echo "Not a numeric value!";
}

?>
```

Comment: So i echo'd the cf_number on the page that the form redirects the user to once they click submit and it isn't displaying anything. :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what Edwin said.

```
$_POST['cf_number'];
```

returns the value of `cf_number`. It comes from the `name` of the input, for example

```
<input type="text" name="myvalue">
<?php $_POST['myvalue']; ?>
```

Obviously you would need to do something with it, for example echo it or send an email using it.